# How can I extract multipart iso files in Mac OS X?

Tags: 3rd-party, iso

E.g.:
part1.iso
part2.iso

I know The Unarchiver can extract a single ISO file, but how can I extract multipart ISO files?

Comment: .iso are CD-ROM images usually. Can't you just mount them by double clicking?

Answer (score 2):

If they are in fact multipart ISO images (instead of two independent ISO files), you can concatenate them at a Terminal prompt:

```
cat part1.iso part2.iso >part.iso
```

I have no idea how to do this from a GUI elegantly.  Perhaps wrap that shell command with Applescript?